# Initialize val property on Kotlin Data Class via Secondary constructor

Tags: kotlin, data-class

```
class Animal {
    val name: String

    constructor(name: String){
        this.name = name // initialized via constructor
    }
}
```

For the above class in `Kotlin` I am able to initialize a **val** property via **secondary constructor** but the same is not allowed for *Data classes*

```
data class User(val name: String, val postalCode: Int) {
    val email: String

    constructor( email: String): this("", 1){
        this.email = email // error: value can not be reassigned
    }

}
```

What I can't understand is, where is the email property is initialized already as I haven't declared any initializes?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If your class has a primary constructor, you *have to* initialize all of its properties "in the primary constructor" - either by directly initializing them at their declaration:

```
val email = "foo@bar.com"
```

Or in an initializer block:

```
val email: String

init {
    email = "foo@bar.com"
}
```

The compiler forces you to forward all secondary constructor calls to the to the primary constructor, and since the primary constructor already has to initialize all properties inside the class (otherwise calling it would construct a partially initialized instance, like in your code example), it wouldn't make sense to also initialize them in the body of the secondary constructor, especially for a `val` which cannot be reassigned.

Comment: Thank you @zsmb13 . Got your point. So, if I declare a `primary constructor` on Animal class, I will get the same error. Actually, I was finding a way to skip a property in data class that will take part in `equals` and `hashcode` methods.

Comment: Indeed, placing those properties in the body is the way to go for that - but you still have to initialize them at the time the primary constructor runs in some manner.